# Lightbox As Global Component (Via Context)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to achieve the following: A full screen lightbox module, in which the user can browse images from some list, or close the lightbox.  Also I want to have the lightbox set up globally, so that every component can connect an image with the lightbox, in the sense that the component renders some thumbnail of the image (or actually whatever it wants), and when you click on it, the lightbox opens up with all images from all components, but the active index set to the image you clicked on.

#### EDIT

Thanks for @AKX's comments, I rewrote the component, now it seems to work.

My idea was to create a context like this

```
function LightboxProvider({ children }) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(-1)
    const { current: items } = useRef([])
    const init = useCallback(function (src, alt, caption) {
        const item = { src, alt, caption }
        if (!items.some((item) => item.src === src)) {
            const ind = items.push(item) - 1
            return {
                onClick() {
                    setActive(ind)
                },
            }
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <LightboxContext.Provider value={init}>
            {children}
            {active >= 0 && <Lightbox items={items} active={active} />}
        </LightboxContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

so every component (below the provider) can do

```
function Image({src, alt, caption}){
  const init = useContext(LightboxContext);
  return <img src={src} alt={alt} {...init(src, caption)}/>;
}
```

This approach *seems* to work, of course I have to reset the provider whenever I render a new page, so the images accross the site don't accumulate in the lightbox.  Still not 100% sure about it, is there a better solution?

Comment: Beyond the immediate problem (modifying state in a render function without a side effect (a no-no), and more precisely modifying state in _another component_ at that time (a bigger no-no)), your approach would never clean up `items` either, so whatever images had, at any given point in time, been rendered would remain in `items`. IOW, this approach won't work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Regarding the last point, I could set up the provider in the page component, so that whenver a new page loads, the provider initializes the list.

Comment: That still wouldn't help with any images you might mount and unmount as you go (e.g. show/hide an accordion, ...).

Comment: True.  For this, I might ID the images and check if the ID is already in the list.  Also I got it working with `items` being a ref instead of a state, i was worried that it will render the Lightbox before it populates `items`, but apparently it renders the Lightbox last, so the approach seems to work :)